# Join two tables using mysql

Tags: mysql, join

table:tab1

```
  id    date_time            zoneid  accountid  slotid     trequest  bidder width   height
_50832  2017-09-04 15:41:06  153     1654       153x468x60  10       aaa      468   60
_50832  2017-09-04 15:41:06  152     1654       152x468x60  10       bbb      468   60
```

table:tab2

```
 id     date_time             zoneid    accountid   slotid      bidder count    
_50832  2017-09-04 15:41:06   152       1654        152x468x60  bbb     6   
_50832  2017-09-04 15:41:06   152       1654        152x468x60  bbb     4   
_50832  2017-09-04 15:41:06   153       1654        153x468x60  aaa     9   
_50832  2017-09-04 15:41:06   153       1654        153x468x60  aaa     1
```

below is my query:

```
SELECT SUM(req.trequest) as REQ, SUM(win.count) as IMP
 FROM tab1  as req
JOIN tab2 as win ON (req.id=win.id AND req.zoneid=win.zoneid)
GROUP BY req.zoneid
```

I get below result,

```
REQ IMP
20  10
20  10
```

IMP count is correct but I get wrong REQ count. My expected result is

```
REQ IMP
10  10
10  10
```

How to get my expected result?

Comment: Why u doing SUM(req.trequest)? i think because of SUM(req.trequest) you got wrong result...

Comment: I need to SUM trequest from tab1 and count from tab2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets find the sum of `trequest` and `count` separately based on zoneid and id.Then use these two results `( t1 and t2 )` in the inner join.

Count mismatch problem shown in the question occur due to multiple rows satisfying the joining conditions.

In this solution we will only have one entry for each `zoneid` in both the results `( t1 and t2 )`. So the problem is avoided.

**Note:** You can remove the `id` column from the `GROUP BY` clause if it doesn't make any difference.

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.zoneid, t1.REQ, t2.IMP FROM

(SELECT id,zoneid,SUM(trequest) as REQ 
 FROM tab1  GROUP BY zoneid,id ) t1

INNER JOIN

(SELECT id,zoneid SUM(win.count) as IMP
 FROM tab2  GROUP BY zoneid,id ) t2

ON t1.id = t2.id 
AND t1.zoneid = t2.zoneid
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's try first sum`win.count` and group records in sub-query, after it join tables. Try in following:

```
SELECT SUM(req.trequest) as REQ, SUM(win.count) as IMP
FROM tab1 as req
JOIN (
    SELECT SUM(win.count) as IMP, win.zoneid, win.id 
    FROM tab2 as win 
    GROUP BY win.zoneid, win.id) AS win ON req.id=win.id AND req.zoneid=win.zoneid
GROUP BY req.zoneid
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `req.zoneid`. You should try `win.zoneid`. What seems is that the rows in table 1 are counted multiple times as zoneid in table 2 comes twice. So `win.zoneid` would group it and avoid the repetition.

Updated: The solution posted by @mayur panchal is the correct one as you don't need to SUM the rows in first table as they belong to different zoneid. If you SUM them you will obviously get the 20 repeated twice.